# Cannot source .bashrc inside cronjob

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to run a python script on a cronjob. To access environment variables in that script, I've wrapped the python script in a short shell script. However, cron does not appear to be accessing my environment correctly, as I'm still getting errors in my python script about not being able to access environment variables. If you consider the below shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/jfeldman/.bashrc
env
```

Running this script from a cronjob yields only this output

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/home/jfeldman
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/home/jfeldman
LOGNAME=jfeldman
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Whereas running that shell script from the command line yields a much larger list of environment variables, including the API tokens that I want to access from my python script. Additionally, my PATH variable is considerably shorter than the cronjob version of `env`

Does anyone know why Cronjobs couldn't access my environment correctly even if the cronjob is running a script that explicitly declares `source /home/jfeldman/.bashrc`?

This is the line from the crontab fwiw
*/5 * * * * /home/jfeldman/crons/test_cron.sh >> /home/jfeldman/crons/test.log 2>&1$`

Edit: after some testing it seems like cron can source my virtual environment just fine, just not .bashrc, which seems incredibly bizarre.

Comment: Put `SHELL=/bin/bash` near the top of your crontab.

Comment: no dice unfortunately @Roadowl. `source` isn't throwing an error which suggests that it's not using sh, but something is still going wrong

Comment: I wonder which env.vars you need in the python script.

Comment: How are you setting the environment variables within your bashrc?

Comment: Without showing the contents of ~/.bashrc, it's a guessing game to say what's happening.

Comment: @SorenBjornstad I'm setting a number of environment variables by `export SOME_TOKEN=SOMETOKEN`

Answer (score 0):

Shell `sh` is not `bash`. `sh` doesn't know the command `source` and possibly wouldn't import `.bashrc` without errors when using it's source command `. /home/user/.bashrc` for sourcing it.

Put the line

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

on top of your `crontab` to run the jobs with bash.

Sourcing a users `.bashrc` to a cronjob running as root user is a bad idea, you could think about creating a job in `/etc/cron.d/` instead, and specify a user other than root running the job.

`5/* * * * * jfeldman /home/jfeldman/cron_runner.sh`

`.bashrc` can change over time it makes sense to copy everyting into the `cron_runner.sh` or even better - create a new user with own home dir just for running the cronjob in a seperate home dir.

Comment: I already tried this without success unfortunately. Even if I don't add that, I think adding the bash shebang should have solved that. As i noted above, the fact that source isn't throwing an error suggests that I am in bash

I've used the cron_runner suggestion as a workaround before but I'm also getting PATH-related problems that I think stem from the same underlying problem so I figured I'd throw the env vars problem on stack overflow bc it's the easiest to explain version of the problem

Comment: SHELL is the variable that tells cron what program to use to run the crontab entries. The shebang has nothing to do with that. Yes you need to set the PATH variable.